# Sending push notifications directly to smart watch

Tags: android, push-notification

I am wondering if sending a push notification to android smart watch is possible without an android smart phone. I want my server to send push notification directly to the smart watch.

How this can be possible?

Answer (score 0):

No. The watch only gets data from the corresponding app on your phone. The watch itself cannot connect to the internet or elsewhere.

Comment: how about if it is a stand alone watch.